# Fast Algorithm to Solve Unique Paths With Backtracking

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, probability, combinatorics

> A robot located at the top left corner of a XxX grid is trying to reach the bottom right corner. The robot can move either up, down, left, or right, but cannot visit the same spot twice. How many possible unique paths are there to the bottom right corner?

What is a **fast** algorithmic solution to this? I've spent a huge amount of time trying to figure out a fast algorithm to this. But still stuck.

This is basically the [unique paths Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-paths/), except with backtracking.

Unique paths, without backtracking, can be solved with dynamic programming such as:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int uniquePaths(int m, int n) {
        vector<int> cur(n, 1);
        for (int i = 1; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
                cur[j] += cur[j - 1];
            }
        }
        return cur[n - 1];
    }
};
```

What would be a fast algorithmic solution, using dynamic programming, to unique paths, **except with backtracking**? Something that could quickly find the result 1,568,758,030,464,750,013,214,100 for a 10X10 grid.

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/aucu9r/how_many_paths_are_there_from_point_a_to_point_b/), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk), and [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4gTV4r0zRs) have resources illustrating the complexity of this problem. But they don't have any answers.

Comment: Why does it need to be **with** backtracking? I suspect a part of description is missing, since backtracking is about *enumerating* and not *counting* the solutions. It's also a bit strange to use backtracking, since you're not really pruning solution space (besides not visiting same spot twice, I guess).

Comment: backtracking as I know is about using recursive function, you can write recursive  backtrack algorithm and use memoization

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-paths/ is not the same. The only operations allowed in that problem is right and down whereas you're allowing up, down, left and right. Do you have link to the original problem statement?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/number-of-simple-paths-between-two-vertices-on-an-n-times-m-square-grid-graph Here's a combinatorics solution

Comment: ["Finding the number of such paths is conjectured to be an NP-hard problem."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk)

Comment: domen: It needs to be with backtracking because that's how the problem was stated; without backtracking the solution is already on LeetCode.........Mukul: The original problem statement is given at the top of the problem.

Comment: There's no "fast" way to do this. You can store locations that you've already visited so that you don't recurse unnecessarily, but there's not trick to this one. Just recursion that will take all day if the grid is really big.

Answer (score 2):

The problem cannot be solved using dynamic programming because the recurrence relation does not break the problem into sub-problems. Dynamic programming assumes that the state to be computed is dependent on only the sub-states in the recurrence. It is not true in this case because there can be cycles, ie. going up and down.

The general case of this problem, to count the number of simple paths in a directed cyclic graph, is considered to be [#P-Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-complete).

This can also been as enumerating [self avoiding walks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk) in 2-dimensions. As per wikipedia,

> Finding the number of such paths is conjectured to be an NP-hard problem<sup>[citation needed]</sup>.

However, if we consider moves in only the positive direction, ie. right and down, it has a closed form solution, of <sup>m+n</sup>C<sub>m</sub>. Basically, the total number of moves is always fixed to be `m + n` where `m`,`n` are cartesian distances to the end point of the diagonal and we simply have to choose the `m` right(s) or `n` down(s). The dynamic programming solution is essentially the same.